# where is the method body of builtin assemblies methods

Tags: c#, methods, assemblies

Consider the following code:

```
int i = 0;        
private void AddValue()
{
    i++;
}
```

When I call AddValue method it has some method body that adds 1 in i. 
Now consiter this:

```
 ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
```

When I call ar.Add(1) it adds and object 1 in ar. when I right click Add and press go to defination i see

```
public virtual int Add(object value);
```

there is no such method body that is adding 1 as object in ar i.e the ArrayList.
my Question is where the hell the method body of ArrayList.Add() is located. how the hell does it add an object to ArrayList when it seems to have no such MethodBody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the code tab's title, it'll say `[from metadata]`. It's not the implementation you're looking at, but *"metadata that appears as C# source code in a read-only buffer"*. See also: [Metadata as Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms236403.aspx).

Comment: ok! then where is the implementation. how can I see the source code of ar.Add(). Is it possible or not??? if it possible then how?? and if it is not possible why then why it is not possible???

Comment: @kashif one question mark already clearly indicates a question. ;-) You can look up the .NET framework source using a decompiler, like heq suggested in another answer. You could take a look at [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx). Why do you want to look at the .NET framework source? The [manual (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add.aspx) clearly describes what each class, method and enum does, so unless you're sure you've encountered a bug in the framework, you usually don't have to look at its source.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation is inside dll. You can use any .NET Decompiler to watch the code. There are number of free decompilers, just use search.